# How can I dump class definition to file from rails console

Tags: rails-console

Say I've been hacking away at something in Rails console and in the process I've created some classes and methods I'd like to keep.  Is there a way to get this code somehow, and dump it to a file or something so I don't need to type it all again (and potentially forget something or make mistakes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out pry: http://pryrepl.org/ It has a nice feature for browsing methods source so probably there will be no difference do the same with class instances.